# How can I randomly add 20 images(10x10) in an empty background image (200x200) in python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, background, geometry

[I want the 10 small images to be placed in this circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCOlH.jpg)

I'm working on a small project to randomly place or put several images of size (10 w x 10 h) in another image that will be used as background of size (200 w x 200 h) in python. The small images should be put at a random location in the background image.

I have 20 small images of size (10x10) and one empty image background of size (200x200). I want to put my 20 small images in the empty background image at a random location in the background.

Is there a way to do it in Python?

Code

```
# Depencies importation
import cv2

# Saving directory
saving_dir = "../Saved_Images/"

# Read the background image
bgimg = cv2.imread("../Images/background.jpg")

# Resizing the bacground image
bgimg_resized = cv2.resize(bgimg, (2050,2050))

# Read the image that will be put in the background image (exemple of 1)
small_img = cv2.imread("../Images/small.jpg")

# Convert the resized background image to gray
bgimg_gray = cv2.cvtColor(bgimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
# Convert the grayscale image to a binary image
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(bgimg_gray,127,255,0)
# Determine the moments of the binary image
M = cv2.moments(thresh)
# calculate x,y coordinate of center
cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

# drawing the circle in the background image
circle = cv2.circle(bgimg, (cX, cY), 930, (0,0,255), 9)

print(circle)

# Saving the new image
cv2.imwrite(saving_dir+"bgimg"+".jpg", bgimg)

cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("Test", 1000, 1200)
# Showing the images
cv2.imshow("image", bgimg)
# Waiting for any key to stop the program execution
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

the above code is for one image, I want to do it for the 20 and to put them in a random location

Comment: What have you tried? What packages are you using? It's certainly doable in Python if I understand your intention. Your question is too broad as is, but if you provide some details and example code, you might get some help.

Comment: I used the paste function (pillow library) and define an area to paste the image in, but I want to put them at random location in the background image and to keep the binary mask.

Code:
from PIL import image
background_img = Image.open("path")
image = Image.open("path)

area = (80, 80, 160, 160)
background_img.paste(image, area)

background_image.show()

the above code is for one image, I want to do it for the 20 and to put them in a random location

Comment: Do your 10x10 images all have similar names so that the program can find them - what are they? Does the background image have a name - other than `"path"`?

Comment: Please do not put code in comment area - it is impossible to read! Click `edit` under your question instead and update your question there for all to see.

Comment: First the  10x10 images have different names like (img1 to img10). The background image has a name (".../bg.jpg")

Comment: Can you share sample explected image?

Comment: @Alderven I updated the code using just opencv. I put the image in the post, but it appears as a link.

Comment: Do you mean the cenres of the 10x10 images should fall in the circle, or the entire 10x10 image should fall in the circle? Does it matter if two 10x10 images overlap each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCOlH.jpg) background image `background.jpg` (decreased to 200x200 px) and 10 images: `image01.png`, `image02.png` ... `image10.png` (10x10 px). Then:

```
import glob
import random
from PIL import Image


img_bg = Image.open('circle.jpg')
width, height = img_bg.size
images = glob.glob('*.png')
for img in images:
    img = Image.open(img)
    x = random.randint(40, width-40)
    y = random.randint(40, height-40)
    img_bg.paste(img, (x, y, x+10, y+10))
img_bg.save('result.png', 'PNG')
```

Output image:

[image]

Comment: I've drawn a circle in the background image as the region of interest to put the 20 small images. The images must be placed inside of the circle. I don't know how to get the coordinates of the drawn circle. When I print the output of the circle, it gives none.

Comment: You can increase offset to make sure that all images will be placed inside the circle. See my updated answer

Comment: The result should like the above image, but, I don't see in where code where you have drawn the circle, because the circle, I drew it to know in which area I will randomly put my small images; however, I still don't know how to get the coordinates of the circle that I have drawn. Once I get the coordinates of the circle I will tell my program to put my small images there. If you look at my code, the circle image is the one I saved (I assume when I put all my small images in the circle I will save that image)

Comment: Your question is about putting images into empty background image, right? So what's the connection with drawing circle?

Comment: At the begining, I didn't have a circle. I drew the circle to define a region where I will randomly put my small images.

I think the following link is so similar to my question about getting the coordinates (pixels) of the circle that I've drawn. I'll take a close look at it...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444660/opencv-get-pixels-on-an-circle

Comment: What if 2 or more boxes in the circle coincide each other, will the code perform as it should? or will it raise `ValueError`