# Can I randomly add a small image (13x12) to an array of pixels (random pixels of the same size of my small image)

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, pixel

I have 20 small images (that I want to put in a target area of a background image (13x12). I have already marked my target area with a circle, I have the coordinates of the circle in two arrays of pixels. Now I want to know how I can randomly add my 20 small images in random area in my arrays of pixels which are basically the target area (the drawn circle).

In my code, I was trying for just one image, if it works, I'll pass the folder of my 20 small images.

[image: Input 1]

```
# Depencies importation
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Saving directory
saving_dir = "../Saved_Images/"

# Read the background image
bgimg = cv2.imread("../Images/background.jpg")

# Resizing the bacground image
bgimg_resized = cv2.resize(bgimg, (2050,2050))

# Read the image that will be put in the background image (exemple of 1)
# I'm just trying with one, if it works, I'll pass the folder of the 20
small_img = cv2.imread("../Images/small.jpg")

# Convert the resized background image to gray
bgimg_gray = cv2.cvtColor(bgimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
# Convert the grayscale image to a binary image
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(bgimg_gray,127,255,0)
# Determine the moments of the binary image
M = cv2.moments(thresh)
# calculate x,y coordinate of center
cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

# Drawing the circle in the background image
circle = cv2.circle(bgimg, (cX, cY), 930, (0,0,255), 9)

print(circle) # This returns None

# Getting the coordinates of the circle
combined = bgimg[:,:,0] + bgimg[:,:,1] + bgimg[:,:,2]
rows, cols = np.where(combined >= 0)

# I have those pixels in rows and cols, but I don't know
# How to randomly put my small image in those pixel

# Saving the new image
cv2.imwrite(saving_dir+"bgimg"+".jpg", bgimg)

cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("Test", 1000, 1200)
# Showing the images
cv2.imshow("image", bgimg)
# Waiting for any key to stop the program execution
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

In the expected results, the small images must be placed in the background image randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the center and the radius of your circle, you can easily generate random coordinates by randomly choosing an angle `theta` from `[0, 2*pi]`, calculating corresponding `x` and `y` values by `cos(theta)` and `sin(theta)` and scaling these by some random chosen scaling factors from `[0, radius]`. I prepared some code for you, see below.

I omitted a lot of code from yours (reading, preprocessing, saving) to focus on the relevant parts (see [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Hopefully, you can integrate the main idea of my solution into your code on your own. If not, I will provide further explanations.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# (Artificial) Background image (instead of reading an actual image...)
bgimg = 128 * np.ones((401, 401, 3), np.uint8)

# Circle parameters (obtained somehow...)
center = (200, 200)
radius = 100

# Draw circle in background image
cv2.circle(bgimg, center, radius, (0, 0, 255), 3)

# Shape of small image (known before-hand...?)
(w, h) = (13, 12)

for k in range(200):

    # (Artificial) Small image (instead of reading an actual image...)
    smallimg = np.uint8(np.add(128 * np.random.rand(w, h, 3), (127, 127, 127)))

    # Select random angle theta from [0, 2*pi]
    theta = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand()

    # Select random distance factors from center
    factX = (radius - w/2) * np.random.rand()
    factY = (radius - h/2) * np.random.rand()

    # Calculate random coordinates for small image from angle and distance factors
    (x, y) = np.uint16(np.add((np.cos(theta) * factX - w/2, np.sin(theta) * factY - h/2), center))

    # Replace (rather than "add") determined area in background image with small image
    bgimg[x:x+smallimg.shape[0], y:y+smallimg.shape[1]] = smallimg

cv2.imshow("bgimg", bgimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The exemplary output:

[image: Output]

Caveat: I haven't paid attention, if the small images might violate the circle boundary. Therefore, some additional checks or limitations to the scaling factors must be added.

---

**EDIT:** I edited my above code. To take the [below comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55609337/can-i-randomly-add-a-small-image-13x12-to-an-array-of-pixels-random-pixels-of/55610945#comment97919431_55610945) into account, I shift the small image by `(width/2, height/2)`, and limit the radius scale factor accordingly, so that the circle boundary isn't violated, neither top/left nor bottom/right.

Before, it was possible, that the boundary is violated in the bottom/right part (`n = 200`):

[image: Violation]

After the edit, this should be prevented (`n = 20000`):

[image: No violation]

The touching of the red line in the image is due to the line's thickness. For "safety reasons", one could add another 1 pixel distance.

Comment: Your code is good, but the small images must not exceed the circle boundary. That's why I wanted to use the circle coordinates to do so

I am trying to adapt your code so that it can fit my need. I mean to find a way to tell my small images that they need to stay inside of the circle.

I have the coordinate of the circle with the following:
`# Getting the coordinates of the circle
combined = bgimg[:,:,0] + bgimg[:,:,1] + bgimg[:,:,2]
rows, cols = np.where(combined >= 0)`

But I haven't found a way yet to do so. When I print rows, cols they are arrays of pixel. 

Thanks @HansHirse

Comment: @EE2017 If you had answered my question about shapes fitting in the circle https://stackoverflow.com/q/55576760/2836621 rather than ignoring me and asking nearly the same question again, you wouldn't have wasted Hans's time that he gives so freely...

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I did answer you. When I answered, I have already solved the first issue. I was just looking for a way to convert my coordinates of the circle that I have as array of pixels.

I'm deeply sorry if you felt so; but I didn't ignore you. Please, consider my apology anyway. This community is too great to have somebody feel sad. Once again, I am sorry.

Let me take a look at #HansHirse answer now...

Comment: @HansHirse Thanks a lot, your answer / code solved my problem. I didn't think about using angle. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to verify your answer, hopefully somebody who can will do it.

Thanks again genius.

Comment: @EE2017 I see, you can't upvote at the moment, but you should be able to mark my answer as accepted, or am I wrong?

Comment: @HansHirse, I thought it was also deactivated for me too since I can't vote yet. It's done now, thanks again.

Truth is I'm polishing your code to make it do something much more complex (like getting input images from different folders, using nested loop...) But the base is yours. 

Thanks again,